# Last tab next button to redirect it home

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was able to add prev and next links between my tabs using the following code. Now when users come to my last tab (4th), I would like them to be redirected to `/home` when they click next. Thank you!

```
    $('#quicktabs-registration_steps').append('<div class="prevnext"><a class="tablink-prev btn btn-default" href="#">Prev</a><a class="tablink-next btn btn-default" href="#">Next</a></div>');
    $('.tablink-prev').click(function(){
        var index = $('.quicktabs-tabs li.active').index();
        $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index).removeClass('active');
        if (index == 0) {
        index = 1;
    }
    $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index - 1).addClass('active');
    $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index - 1).find('a').click();
        return false;
    });
    $('.tablink-next').click(function(){
        var length = $('.quicktabs-tabs').first().children().size();;
        var index = $('.quicktabs-tabs li.active').index();
        $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index).removeClass('active');
            if (parseInt(index) == parseInt(length) - 1 ) {
                index = index - 1;
            }
        $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index + 1).addClass('active');
        $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index + 1).find('a').click();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: `if (parseInt(index) == parseInt(length) - 1 ) {
                index = index - 1;
            }` 
why are you doing this?

Comment: @MahbubMoon it stops it from moving from last tab to first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul class="quicktabs-tabs">
          <li class="active">tab1</li>
          <li>tab2</li>
          <li>tab3</li>
          <li>tab4</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="tablink-prev">Prev</button>
        <button class="tablink-next">Next</button>
        <script>
            $('#quicktabs-registration_steps').append('<div class="prevnext"><a class="tablink-prev btn btn-default" href="#">Prev</a><a class="tablink-next btn btn-default" href="#">Next</a></div>');
            $('.tablink-prev').click(function(){
                var index = $('.quicktabs-tabs li.active').index();
                $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index).removeClass('active');
                if (index == 0) {
                index = 1;
            }
            $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index - 1).addClass('active');
            $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index - 1).find('a').click();
                return false;
            });
            $(".tablink-next").click(function(){
                var length = $('.quicktabs-tabs').first().children().length;
                var index = $('.quicktabs-tabs li.active').index();
                $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index).removeClass('active');
                if (parseInt(index) == parseInt(length) - 1 ) {

                    window.location.href = '/home'; //redirect to home
                    //index = index - 1;
                }
                $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index + 1).addClass('active');
                $('.quicktabs-tabs li').eq(index + 1).find('a').click();
                return false;
            })

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

when last tab has active class and then press next control comes in if condition and if (parseInt(index) == parseInt(length) - 1 ) condition become true and redirect to home routes